# Docker pull fails with "failed to register layer: sync ... input/output error"

Tags: docker

Attempting to pull a docker image and got the following result:

```
2f94e549220a: Pull complete 
72007112f52f: Pull complete 
e1886834052f: Pull complete 
934c6c525c1d: Pull complete 
6bc1674f1e8f: Pull complete 
07e666cf45ea: Pull complete 
609b62e99828: Extracting   5.23GB/5.23GB
bbd38441b44b: Download complete 
4e6cf32e909d: Download complete 
3ed8401905bf: Download complete 
failed to register layer: sync /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/tmp/write-set-315662188/diff: input/output error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the `input/output error`, and knowing that I had less than ~10GB left on my drive, I cleaned up some more space and reran the pull command. Error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error in Gitlab job based upon Docker DIND and launching `docker pull`. The problem was solved after upgrading Docker DIND to newer version (20.10.24 suffices for problem disappearance).